# Using a US-bought WiFi iPad in the UK with the AppStore?

Tags: ipad, itunes, internationalization

I'm looking to give a WiFi-only iPad to a family member as a gift this Christmas. However, I'm concerned that since I am located in the UK, and the device I purchase will be 'US' configured for the store, etc, I will be unable to configure it to work correctly as a UK iPad, with the correct iTunes store, etc.

Is the iTunes store (app, music, video) related to the device software, the network it's accessing from, or the locale of the iTunes account associated with that device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The iTunes store is related to the locale of the iTunes account (which is determined by the credit card associated with the account). Several friends of mine have bought iPads in other countries (US and UK) and are happily using them in Sweden with the Swedish iTunes store.

Answer (score 5):

Specifically, the locale of the iTunes account is **determined by the country of your associated credit card (or gift card).**

If you entered a UK credit card in your iTunes account, then iTuens will show you only content released in the UK. This is true regardless where the device was bought, and regardless what regional settings and UI language is used.

Comment: Not exactly true, I live in Australia and have managed to obtain a US account through some coupon-code trickery. Of course, I've never used it apart from a failed attempt at getting the LastFM app, but it is possible to get an account without associating a credit card.